# Advance Search Not Working With Custom Atrtribute

Tags: magento2, product, php, search, advanced-search

I have modified the advance search form and added only my custom attributes in the form,

I have created the Select input with the exact same values from product attributes like:

```
<select name="make" id="make">
   <option value="">Please Select...</option>
   <option value="passend für Audi / Seat">passend für Audi / Seat</option>
   <option value="passend für Audi / VW">passend für Audi / VW</option>
   <option value="passend für VM">passend für VM</option>
</select>
```

In the admin i have the value for Make attribute like this, it is same as in SELECT input on frontend:
[image]

And on frontend where i have created the Select input has the same value to search:

[image]

But now when i try to search the products with this attribute in advance search it is not showing any products, as the product is assigned the attribute and has correct value.

Other attribute that is "Year" and having the Digits value is working fine with the same form.

[image]

Is there any settings or configuration i am missing for attributes or search?

I have cleared all the caches, Run the Indexer as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to set the attribute to be used in search as well as to make it visible in advanced search by editing the attribute properties in **admin -> attribute edit page -> Storefront properties -> Use in Search = yes & Visible in Advanced Search = yes**

> **Visible in Advanced Search** — Gives shoppers the ability to enter search criteria through a form.

**and not adding the dropdown manually in the advanced search form**.

You basically want Magento to do the trick for you and to have the attribute values indexed in your search engine so that you have results when using it in the advanced search form.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I have set attribute to Visible in advance search and use in search to yes as well.

So actually i need a dropdown input on the frontend so the customer can easily view and select the option, rather type in input field.

somehow search work if i change the attribute values to a single word like I have tried with "Make" as attribute value in product and select field and it was working fine,

the only thing not working when i used my actually values that are shown above.

Comment: if you intend to use it as select box in the advanced search page, then yes, it needs to be a select attribute. But the text fields should also work if you want it to be a text box. the idea is that it has to be the same type on both admin and frontend, not text in admin and select in frontend.

Comment: But my concern is, it works fine when i change the product attributes values something like "Make" , "Model" as shown in screenshot it works fine, with the same Custom Drop down and attribute type TEXT, how you see this case? how it is working with some values but not with others?
https://www.screencast.com/t/j8ken9WSG

Comment: and you are completely sure you have the 'other values' saved on products? try running a reindexation and cache flush, then see if you still have the issue.

Comment: As i have attached the screenshot with main question you can see the values there, and yes the cache and re-indexing is also done

Comment: can you confirm you removed the select box you manually added in the form and left only the attributes displayed and managed by magento there?

Comment: Also tried with the text input and it is also not working fine
https://www.screencast.com/t/DpLBzcoNbU

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120321/discussion-between-diana-botean-and-shoaib-munir).